# Twitter Bootstrap table editable json data

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

Why can't i use bootstrap editable table in this way?

```
<table id="addElements" data-height="299">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-field="id" data-align="right">Item ID</th>
            <th data-field="element" data-align="center">Element</th>
            <th data-field="weight" data-align="">Težina</th>
            <th data-field="default_thickness" data-align="">Debljina</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>


    //put data in js variable and fill the table
var elementData = [{
    "id": "1",
    "element": "c",
    "weight": "20",
    "default_thickness": "6"
}, {
    "id": "2",
    "element": "k",
    "weight": "21",
    "default_thickness": "2"
}, {
    "id": "3",
    "element": "p",
    "weight": "18",
    "default_thickness": "2"
}];
$(function () {
    $('#addElements').bootstrapTable({
        data: elementData
    });
})

$.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';
    $('td').editable({
            url: '/post',
            type: 'text',
            pk: 1,
            name: 'parket',
            title: 'Enter username'
        });
```

In this fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/aleksacavic/03agu1ex/1/
it works, when clicked, table cells are in edit mode. But identical code on my site is not working? What am i missing? As i can see, on my side, when clicked, cells are not allowed to change class, only table thread gets highlighted, additional element (input field) not being created.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed the ready function, due to this jquery is not able to bind the data.

```
//put data in js variable and fill the table
$(window).bind("load", function() {
    var elementData = [{
        "id": "1",
        "element": "c",
        "weight": "20",
        "default_thickness": "6"
    }, {
        "id": "2",
        "element": "k",
        "weight": "21",
        "default_thickness": "2"
    }, {
        "id": "3",
        "element": "p",
        "weight": "18",
        "default_thickness": "2"
    }];
    $(function () {
        $('#addElements').bootstrapTable({
            data: elementData
        });
    })


$.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';
        $('a').editable({
            url: '/post',
            type: 'text',
            pk: 1,
            name: 'parket',
            title: 'Enter username'
        });
    $('td').editable({
            url: '/post',
            type: 'text',
            pk: 1,
            name: 'parket',
            title: 'Enter username'
        });
});
```

[image: by running the script in console it worked for me]

Comment: thanks for answer. Did that. Everything is identical. just now I created mockup just for this purpose civil.cavic.me/fiddle.html

Comment: i wrapped everything in .ready function as you suggested but on my end nothing changes. I can see on your screenshot its working... :@

Comment: $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';
        $('a').editable({
            url: '/post',
            type: 'text',
            pk: 1,
            name: 'parket',
            title: 'Enter username'
        });
    $('td').editable({
            url: '/post',
            type: 'text',
            pk: 1,
            name: 'parket',
            title: 'Enter username'
        });
});

run this code on browser console and check it once

Comment: Yes it works when runs on console. But it seems <table> is cause of problem, could you check the link again? I put link on the page and it works on it, but on <td> element it doesn't.

Comment: can you please check the updated answer, we have to use(tested in my local sys)-- 
$(window).bind("load", function() {

Comment: it worked. Thanks. Can you please elaborate why document.ready wasn't able to perform?

Comment: You are using cdn links to libs, before loading/rendering  those scripts $.fn.editable.defaults.mode is getting executed. we have to make sure that all scripts were **loaded completely**.
It is always better to write our custom script in jquery load function.

Answer (score 0):

try and add delay on load, should fix it:

```
setTimeout(function(){
            $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';
            var a = $('a');
            $('a').editable({
                type: 'text',
                pk: 1,
                name: 'parket',
                title: 'Enter username'
            });
            $('td').editable({
                type: 'text',
                pk: 1,
                name: 'parket',
                title: 'Enter username'
            });
        },500);
```